# Error creating bean: Injection of autowired dependencies failed;

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, tomcat7

I have a maven project which has spring framework integrated in it and i used this project to build web services for the mobile app. The project gives BeanCreationException when i deploy it on AWS ubuntu server and it fails to run on tomcat7. Where as it works fine when i run it in local environment. Below is the error log of tomcat7.

```
ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(318) | Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'userManager' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userManager': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void com.washkart.www.service.impl.UserManagerImpl.setUserDao(com.washkart.www.dao.UserDao); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDao': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-dao.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.search.SearchException: HSEARCH000103: Unable to initialize IndexManager com.washkart.www.model.User
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:627)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:148)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1114)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1017)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:381)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:293)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5068)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5584)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1091)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1980)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userManager': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void com.washkart.www.service.impl.UserManagerImpl.setUserDao(com.washkart.www.dao.UserDao); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDao': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-dao.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.search.SearchException: HSEARCH000103: Unable to initialize IndexManager com.washkart.www.model.User
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:320)
        ... 30 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void com.washkart.www.service.impl.UserManagerImpl.setUserDao(com.washkart.www.dao.UserDao); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDao': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-dao.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.search.SearchException: HSEARCH000103: Unable to initialize IndexManager com.washkart.www.model.User
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
        ... 38 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDao': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-dao.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.search.SearchException: HSEARCH000103: Unable to initialize IndexManager com.washkart.www.model.User
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:307)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:957)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:553)
        ... 40 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-dao.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.search.SearchException: HSEARCH000103: Unable to initialize IndexManager com.washkart.www.model.User
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:445)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:419)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:544)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:150)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:304)
        ... 51 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.search.SearchException: HSEARCH000103: Unable to initialize IndexManager com.washkart.www.model.User
        at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.IndexManagerHolder.createDirectoryManager(IndexManagerHolder.java:244)
        at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.IndexManagerHolder.buildEntityIndexBinding(IndexManagerHolder.java:111)
        at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchFactoryBuilder.initDocumentBuilders(SearchFactoryBuilder.java:411)
        at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchFactoryBuilder.buildNewSearchFactory(SearchFactoryBuilder.java:221)
        at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchFactoryBuilder.buildSearchFactory(SearchFactoryBuilder.java:145)
        at org.hibernate.search.event.impl.FullTextIndexEventListener.initialize(FullTextIndexEventListener.java:129)
        at org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.HibernateSearchIntegrator.integrate(HibernateSearchIntegrator.java:82)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:304)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1794)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1865)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:339)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:427)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:412)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
        ... 63 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.search.SearchException: Unable to initialize directory provider: com.washkart.www.model.User
        at org.hibernate.search.store.impl.DirectoryProviderFactory.createDirectoryProvider(DirectoryProviderFactory.java:87)
        at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.DirectoryBasedIndexManager.createDirectoryProvider(DirectoryBasedIndexManager.java:216)
        at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.DirectoryBasedIndexManager.initialize(DirectoryBasedIndexManager.java:89)
        at org.hibernate.search.indexes.impl.IndexManagerHolder.createDirectoryManager(IndexManagerHolder.java:241)
        ... 77 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.search.SearchException: Unable to create index directory: /usr/share/tomcat7/baseapp-1.0/index for index com.washkart.www.model.User
        at org.hibernate.search.store.impl.DirectoryProviderHelper.makeSanityCheckedDirectory(DirectoryProviderHelper.java:261)
        at org.hibernate.search.store.impl.DirectoryProviderHelper.getVerifiedIndexDir(DirectoryProviderHelper.java:243)
        at org.hibernate.search.store.impl.FSDirectoryProvider.initialize(FSDirectoryProvider.java:66)
        at org.hibernate.search.store.impl.DirectoryProviderFactory.createDirectoryProvider(DirectoryProviderFactory.java:84)
        ... 80 more
DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1] StartupListener.contextInitialized(47) | Initializing context...
Apr 26, 2017 8:16:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
Apr 26, 2017 8:16:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
Apr 26, 2017 8:16:25 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Apr 26, 2017 8:16:25 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Apr 26, 2017 8:16:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deployment of web application archive /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT.war has finished in 9,539 ms
Apr 26, 2017 8:16:25 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Apr 26, 2017 8:16:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 12078 ms
```

My `hibernate.cfg` looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <mapping class="com.washkart.www.model.User"/>
    <mapping class="com.washkart.www.model.Role"/>
    <mapping class="com.washkart.www.model.WashUser"/>
    <mapping class="com.washkart.www.model.WashOrder"/>
    <mapping class="com.washkart.www.model.Service"/>
    <mapping class="com.washkart.www.model.Item"/>
    <mapping class="com.washkart.www.model.Device"/>
    <mapping class="com.washkart.www.model.Offer"/>
    <mapping class="com.washkart.www.model.Employee"/>
    <mapping class="com.washkart.www.model.Attendance"/>

    <mapping class="com.washkart.www.model.Rates"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And the applicationContext-dao.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd"
   default-lazy-init="true">

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateExceptionTranslator"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

<!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" destroy-method="destroy">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.query.substitutions">true 'Y', false 'N'</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</prop>
            <!-- Hibernate Search index directory -->
            <prop key="hibernate.search.default.indexBase">${app.search.index.basedir}</prop>
        </props>
        <!-- Turn batching off for better error messages under PostgreSQL -->
        <!-- hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=0 -->
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Transaction manager for a single Hibernate SessionFactory (alternative to JTA) -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<!-- Activates scanning of @Autowired -->
<context:annotation-config/>

<!-- Activates scanning of @Repository -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.washkart.www.dao"/>

</beans>
```

The project works fine in one of the old AWS server but it crashes on new server. I am very new to spring security framework and don't have much idea about. The base project had spring security integrated.

Help me to resolve the error.

TIA

Comment: what is the value of `${app.search.index.basedir}`

Comment: app.search.index.basedir=target/index

Comment: is that path writable in the new environment? Are the folder permissions the same? (I assume you were on linux in both environments)

Comment: I had taken the Ubuntu ec2 t2 micro instance in both

Comment: Is there more error log?

Comment: Updated the question with full log from where it carshes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142773/discussion-between-qtips-and-aashish-gulabani).

Answer (score 0):

You Exception log says:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.search.SearchException: Unable to create index directory: /usr/share/tomcat7/baseapp-1.0/index for index com.washkart.www.model.User
```

check that you that this directory exists and that your program has write permission to this path. For example, ssh to the new server and do the following:

```
cd /usr/share/tomcat7/baseapp-1.0/
chmod -R 775 .
```

Comment: index directory should be automatically created when tomcat starts, Although i checked there is no sub directory baseapp-1.0 under tomcat7

Comment: or maybe `${app.search.index.basedir}` must be `baseapp-1.0/index`. But that should be the case in both environments.

Comment: baseapp-1.0 is the directory path of project. And there is no such sub directory in tomcat7 folder

Comment: lets continue this discussion in chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142773/discussion-between-qtips-and-aashish-gulabani